# If $\sigma(n)=\sigma(n+2)$ is $\sigma(n+1)-1$ always prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$\sigma(n)$ denotes the divisor function which sums the divisors of an integer $n \geq 1$.

If we have $\sigma(n)=\sigma(n+2)$ is $\sigma(n+1)-1$ always prime?

I failed to create a program to check the conjecture.

For example $\sigma(54)=\sigma(56)$ and $\sigma(55)-1=71$

Another example is $\sigma(33)=\sigma(35)$ and $\sigma(34)-1=53$

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to base a conjecture on two small values?  Why?  It's really pointless to look at this kind of question if you aren't going try a search.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true in general.  There are two counterexamples for $1 \le n \le 1000$, according to the attached Rust program (using the `num-prime` crate):

\begin{align*}
&\sigma(834) = \sigma(836) = 1680, & &\sigma(835) = 1007 \\
&\sigma(848) = \sigma(850) = 1674, & &\sigma(849) = 1135 \\
\end{align*}

```
type Number = u64;

const SEARCH_MAX: Number = 1000;

fn divisor_sum(n: Number) -> Number {
    (1..=n).filter(|d| n % d == 0).sum()
}

fn main() {
    use num_prime::nt_funcs::is_prime64;

    for n in 1..=SEARCH_MAX {
        let divisor_sum_of_n = divisor_sum(n);
        if divisor_sum_of_n != divisor_sum(n + 2) {
            continue;
        }
        let conjectured_prime = divisor_sum(n + 1) - 1;
        if !is_prime64(conjectured_prime) {
            println!(
                r#"&\sigma({}) = \sigma({}) = {}, & &\sigma({}) = {} \\"#,
                n,
                n + 2,
                divisor_sum_of_n,
                n + 1,
                conjectured_prime
            );
        }
    }
}
```